# Get items from seq traits in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm looking for an elegant way to get elements by generated array consisting of indices

```
create a seq
```

`val nums = Seq(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 14, 12, 16)`

```
create a slice
```

`val i = Array.range(2, 10, 3)`
`Array[Int] = Array(2, 5, 8)`

How to get 3, 7, 14 from Seq?

Comment: I don't understand the question, do you have some specific indexes? Do you have an start, end and step?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly, you want to pick elements from `nums` corresponding to indexes from `i`.

The most elegant way I can think of it:

```scala
i.map(nums.apply)
```

scastie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/KacperFKorban/ckwx5KMKQMOss1L0ce661w

Comment: i think using map is not cool solution, i search some equal of cycle for slice without many words, i trying to find equal of python's nums[2:10:3]

Comment: `map` is the Scala way to do it. Having a special-cased language syntactic sugar for such a rare operation seems useless to me. Also, I don't think that python's untyped, error-prone operations are a good comparison to Scala.